# How to display results in parent window after form submission in showModelDialog box using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, struts2

I am facing a complex situation in which parent window is calling showModelDialog box to submit a form.
When form is submitted it goes to a struts2 action. Action does some work and then redirects to parent page again.
Thus full parent page is refreshed again. I want that after user click on submit in child window. Child window should close and results needs to be updated only on specific part of parent window.

function calling child window:

```
function createRegularFile()
    {
     var userAgent =  navigator.userAgent;
    var appName = navigator.appName;
    window.name="WorklistFiles";
    alert("before="+UserFiles.innerHTML);
    if(appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {       window.showModalDialog("createFilePrepareFilesAction.action",window,"help:no;dialogheight:400px;dialogwidth:500px;status:0;");
        }
    else{var abc=window.open("createFilePrepareFilesAction.action","window","HEIGHT=400,WIDTH=500,screenX=80,left=300,screenY=50,top=200,scrollbars=1,resizable=yes");
}
```

function in child window:

```
function create()
{   
    //other code 
    document.createRegularFile.action="createFileFilesAction.action";
    document.createRegularFile.submit();
    window.close();
}
```

Action code:

```
createFile()
{
//some code.
return "parent"
}
```

Struts.xml:

```
<result name="parent" type="redirect-action">
                <param name="actionName">worklistWorklistAction</param>
                <param name="error">${error.get(0)}</param>
</result>
```

Parent.jsp

```
Contains code which displays a table using <s:iterator>
```

Only this table needs to be updated after successful submission. I know how to use AJAX but not able to find way to implement it in this situation.

Comment: Use ajax instead of submitting the form. It will refresh your page. You can call a ajax function on click on the button and by this function u can pass the required values to database. And after the success you can close the child wind using javascript.

Comment: @Nikz Thanks for reply. Actually that action code takes lot of time to execute. If we wait for ajax to successfully return on child itself it looks like application has hanged. Can you suggest a way that child closes instantly on submit and parent updates only after action success. Till that time a progessbar can be shown on parent page.

Comment: Its simple.. Use the code which used in success function directly at the (end of funtion). By this The child will close onclick of the button and in background the ajax function runs.

Comment: @Nikz Not able to understand. can you give an example or elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Outline for closing the child

```
<input type="button" onclick="ajax_call();" />

function to_close_child()
{
// code to close child window

}

function ajax_call()
{
//ajaxfunction
  success
   {
     // no need to call on success func
   }


// call the close function here only
to_close_child();
}
```

Comment: In above code action is being called and also child window closes instantaneously but How we will know the result of action as success cant be used.